# JSON formatting in java / akka

Tags: java, json, akka

Holla all, I've been having a simple error at work and need some help

our json object is erroring out with the wrong format for null

This is what we want for the json
"tea" : "",   <- success
this is what we are getting
"tea" : null, <- failing

Here is the code I'm working with

```
List<Delivery_Request> process(BasicSourceObject payload, shardRoutingEnvelope){
  JSONObject itemBarcode = null;
  String tea = null;

  if(payload != null){
  String itemRequestJSON = new String(payload.getPayload());
  JSONObject jsonOBJ = null;
  try{
    jsonObj = new JSONObject(pricingRequestJson);
    if(!itemBarcode.isNull("tea")){

    Here I'm getting the String from the json TEA but how to I replace it with a correct json value?

    tea = itemBarcode.getString("tea");
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getJsonString-java.lang.String-) the method you called will return "null if this object contains no mapping for the name":

> JsonString getJsonString(String name)
>
> Returns the string value to which the specified name is mapped. This is a convenience method for (JsonString)get(name) to get the value.
>
> Parameters:
> name - the name whose associated value is to be returned
>
> Returns:
> the string value to which the specified name is mapped, or null if this object contains no mapping for the name
>
> Throws: ClassCastException - if the value to which the specified name is mapped is not assignable to JsonString type

Therefore, I would suggest:

```
tea = itemBarcode.getString("tea")!=null? itemBarcode.getString("tea"): "";
```

Or alternatively:

```
tea = itemBarcode.getString("tea");
if(tea==null) tea = "";
```